# parse_named_entities function returning nothing

Tags: python, node.js

I'm using spacy-nlp to interface between nodejs and python code from Spacy library. Follow the steps in https://github.com/kengz/spacy-nlp/blob/master/README.md but unsuccessfully. My script.js is as follow:

```
const spacyNLP = require("spacy-nlp")

const serverPromise = spacyNLP.server({ port: process.env.IOPORT })

const nlp = spacyNLP.nlp

const text = "On 22 June 1941, the European Axis powers launched an invasion of the Soviet Union, 
    opening the largest land theatre of war in history, which trapped the Axis, most crucially the German 
    Wehrmacht, into a war of attrition. World War II (often abbreviated to WWII or WW2), also known as 
    the Second World War, was a global war that lasted from 1939 to 1945."

const options = ['word']

nlp
  .parse_named_entities(
    text,
    options
  )
  .then(output => {
    console.log(output)
  })
```

So in VSCode I run

```
node script.js
```

The execution prints out

```
[Fri Apr 03 2020 00:00:46 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)] INFO Starting poly-socketio server on 
    port: 6466, expecting 1 IO clients
[Fri Apr 03 2020 00:00:46 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)] INFO Starting socketIO client for 
    python3 at 6466
```

but nothing is logged.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks